# Careers -- instead of distance, calculate actual commute distance (or better yet avg commute time)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I don't really care how far a place is from my home zip-code. I really care about if the commute is reasonable. As-the-crow-flies-distance is an extremely poor metric for commute quality in many regions. Case-in-point, the Washington, DC region:

In the DC area, where I live, many are either on the Maryland or Virginia side of the  Potomac. Because the Potomac has few crossings, it can be difficult to get between Maryand and Virginia during rush hour. A Marylander may be able to toss a football over to her buddy in Virginia, but to drive to see her buddy might take an hour or more. When said Marylander goes to look for a job, she's much more interested in jobs 5 miles deeper into Maryland than the one 100 yds away in Virginia, across the Potomac.

There's useful mapping/directions information out there on google maps and the like. In fact, [here's a tutorial](http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/) for how to calculate travel distance with google maps API in javascript. Can't we automagicaly use that to help careers users find jobs with the shortest commutes and up the awesome even further? Even if careers had zip-code to zip-code, that would be worth it.

Comment: Interesting idea, but probably too hard to implement, at least on a global scale. Even with Google's help, there are bound to be exceptions it can't map, especially in complex urban areas

Answer (score 1):

If you work in London the vast majority of people commute via the train or bus, so I can see there being many exceptions to the rule.

Comment: well google does do mass transit directions...

Comment: @doug It's a good idea, I'm just saying it might not work for every country, particularly London with the tubes we have. It could be US only though

Answer (score 1):

While this is a good suggestion in theory, we have a feeling that the exceptions will be few and far between. Pair that with people's different commute tolerances, the work involved in getting this to work across the board and all the other things we have to work on, and the result is a status-declined (of course, never say never - there is always a slim change we'll revisit this at some later time).

Ultimately, the people that are affected by these hard to commute distances will know when they hit a case like that and will at that time be able to make the decision if the added travel time is worth their while.